# Nullpointer Exception - Concurrent Hashmap

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I want to increase a counter for a ConcurrentHashmap, but the key can be deleted at any time by another thread. So I check if the key still exists before increasing the counter.

I have the following code:

```
if(this.myMap.containsKey(key))
{
    this.myMap.put(key, this.myMap.get(key) + 1);
}
```

myMap is created like this:

```
private Map<String, Integer> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

But from time to time I get a NullPointer Exception in the line where I increase the integer.
This doesn't happen often (maybe 1 out of 10 Million runs).

Is there another way to increase the counter? Or Do I even need a HashMap?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.. Did you even read my question? I know what a Nullpointer is, that's why I check if the key exists.

Comment: did you ever consider that your check happens and then the entry gets deleted before you do the `.get()` that is what happens with concurrent code. `ConcurrentHashMap` does not guarantee what you think it does.

Comment: That's exactly my problem, and I thought you would help me out. Edit: Thanks @davidxxx, is there a simple way to solve this?

Comment: read for comprehension the answers to **ALL** the duplicates listed

Comment: Of course, synchronize the set of instructions with the `synchronized` keyword

Comment: @davidxxx - that will not stop another thread from removing something, that is a completely naive *solution* that is not a solution, concurrency is much more than slinging `synchronized` keywords around randomly until it *works* until it does not work.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson  Synchronize the map instance will not be enough ???

Comment: so how does putting the `contains` and `get` in a `synchronized` block stop another thread from calling `remove` between their execution?

Comment: You don't answer to the question. The synchronized statement on the map instance will prevent NPE and inconsistency. The removal from another thread will happen **before** or **after** the  synchronized statement.

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you're going to need to use `computeIfPresent.` If not, you'll need to do a `replace` loop.

Comment: What about this?
<pre>
private Map<String, AtomicInteger> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();
    
    public void add(String key){
        AtomicInteger ai = myMap.get(key);
        if (ai != null) ai.addAndGet(1);
    }
 <code>

Comment: What, if I use this: `this.myMap.put(key, this.myMap.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);` Is it safe to use? Additionally I don't have to check if it exists.